# android resolve .local (mDNS)

Tags: android, network-programming, jmdns, mdns

I'm looking for a solution to resolve .local host names with Android 4.0.4 (no NSD, due to API level 15). On the device I don't have any service to discover, just the hostname.
Could you please provide an example how to resolve? I integrated the jmDNS, but don't know how to use for host name resolving.

win-cmd:

```
ping kcmeasurement.local

Pinging kcmeasurement.local [10.202.0.29] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.202.0.29: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
...
```

Thank you,

Daniel

Comment: This is a shortcoming of Android.  If you want it fixed in the OS, please drop by and *star* (upvote) [this android buganizer issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140786115).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had almost the same requirements as your question, apart from the requirement to use jmDNS, so I solved it with NSD. I realize this doesn't address your question exactly, but thought it might still be somewhat helpful for yourself and others to see how I solved it.

I setup an NSD discovery listener and an NSD resolve listener, and within the discovery listener code, added a filter for the target host name (e.g. "kcmeasurement", or in my case, "garagedoor").

There is a blog post here which explains in detail how to do that. Refer to steps 3-4, which are dealing with the Android App code required.

http://www.dodgycoder.net/2015/02/setting-up-bonjourzeroconfmdnsnsd.html

For your case, I would imagine you would have to do the equivalent process but just using the jmDNS library instead of NSD.

Comment: This appears to be about resolving an mDNS *service* rather than resolving  a *name* - in particular, the writeup proposes changing the configuration of the raspberry pi, rather than merely recognizing the rapsberrypi.local mDNS name it should already have out of the box.

Comment: I just managed to reach RPi from PC, - only after I installed samba and restarted avahi-daemon. No luck from Android

Comment: the issue with android is that it doesn't ship with an mdns service. .local addresses are handled by avahi in Linux and bonjour in ios/macos. jmdns or the nsd app should enable that

Answer (score -6):

You should be able to use the `InetAddress` class to resolve the hostname for a given IP address. For example, using the IP address provided in the original question, try the following:

```
try
{
    String hostname = InetAddress.getByName("10.202.0.29").getHostName();
}
catch (UnknownHostException e)
{
    Log.e("MyApplication", "Attempt to resolve host name failed");
}
```

Since this is a network operation, make sure that it is not performed on the UI thread.

**EDIT**

You should be able to resolve a local hostname with jmDNS as follows:

```
InetAddress localHost = InetAddress.getByName("10.202.0.29");
JmDNS jmdns = JmDNS.create(localHost);
String localHostName = jmdns.getHostName();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Unfortunately It's not working, because the "kcmeasurement" is an mDNS host name and my android version (4.0.4) doesn't have a built-in mDNS resolver. So if I call the InetAddress.getByName I got a not found exception.

Comment: Moreover I included the jmDNS package into my Apk, so the advertising works, but I don't find how to resolve .local names.

Comment: -1 Neither the original nor amended form of this answer address the actual question **at all**. It's likely that you did not understand what was being asked - the so called local "name" you claim to be resolving in the second part is neither an mDNS name nor any sort of name at all, it's a numeric IP address, and there's no need to "resolve" that at all.

Comment: I am just using the IP address to create a 'InetAddress' object. The host name is found by calling 'getHostName'.

Comment: That's not what was asked.  The question is about turning a name like "kcmeasurement.local" into an IP address. Once you have a numeric IP address, you're done.  You *started* with a numeric IP address, which makes your response completely inapplicable to the problem of the question asked - you're assuming prior knowledge of the very thing the question is about discovering!