# Accessing raspberry pi in my local network from android devices in Ionic Framework

Tags: android, networking, raspberry-pi, ionic-framework

I am new to raspberry pi and ionic. We give some domain name to raspberry pi like fun.local. I encounter with one problem of network discovery. I have raspberry pi and we stored some procedures at that device. Now we want to access those api from Ionic Application. Now If we tested on MAC it is working for simulator and browser. API is accessible from there. But when we  trying to connect our android phone to API then raspberry pi is not detected.

I think there may be issue of hostname. I have some trace like bonjour(MAC) and UPnP(Windows,Linux) which are protocol for hostname. I think because of this I am unable detect raspberry pi in my android device.

If you have any solution for this problem please let me know. If you need more information then mention in comments.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A very good answer for the very thing you want to do is found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28793299/4295037

In it, you'll find a link to a tutorial showing how to resolve a raspberry-pi .local address in an Android device.

You might also want to take a look at this repo: https://github.com/promovicz/better-zeroconf

Before you start clicking the links, though, it is important to not confuse between bonjour and UPnP, these are two different protocols used for different things. The former is for zero configuration and the latter is for well, configuring services in your network.

As a side note, be advised:
"By default, mDNS only and exclusively resolves host names ending with the .local" [From: Wikipedia]