# How to access raspberry.local in my android application?

Tags: android, dns, raspberry-pi2, mdns, jmdns

I am running Django on my raspberry-pi, and I am using **avahi-daemon** to access my rpi on **raspberrypi.local** . On my Django I have made APIs for my android application to access via HTTP protocol. For example one of my http request url is:  `http://raspberrypi.local/api/getUserNames/`

The problem is that android is not accessing this url on my local wifi network, i have confirmed that my android device and rpi are both connected to same wifi network, but still the `http://raspberrypi.local` is not working on android. While it works fine on my PC & MAC.

I tried to find the solution and went through many Q&A explaining about bonjour, mDNS, jmDNS, android-multicast. But all are either too confusing to implement or doesn't work. Please help me, I'm stuck for a while.

**NOTE:**  on my Rpi the avahi-daemon is broadcasting itself as *"_workstation._tcp." service-type*

--

**My Solution:**

http://www.dodgycoder.net/2015/02/setting-up-bonjourzeroconfmdnsnsd.html

Android NSD (Network Service Discovery) solved my problem. I used only Discovery Listener and Resolve Listener to solve my purpose.
I specifically used `SERVICE_TYPE = "_workstation._tcp.";` in order to search for raspberrypi.local with *avahi-daemon*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Android NSD (Network Service Discovery)* solved my problem. I used only Discovery Listener and Resolve Listener to solve my purpose.

**NOTE-** You'll have to use `SERVICE_TYPE = "_workstation._tcp.";` in order to search for raspberrypi.local with avahi-daemon

here's link to the solution - http://www.dodgycoder.net/2015/02/setting-up-bonjourzeroconfmdnsnsd.html

Comment: This is really something else than was asked - while *some* systems may advertise a _workstation._tcp service, that's really quite distinct from an mDNS *hostname* which is what the question is about.  In particular, this approach won't work for systems that don't advertise that.

Comment: I posted the question too, it's about how to access the webapp hosted on a Rpi's port 80 on an android application. Using avahi-daemon (http://raspberrypi.local)

Comment: This may work for you, **but it is not an answer to your original question** - what you've done is *change* the raspberry pi to *advertise a service* and then *resolved an instance of that service* - you haven't actually looked up the mDNS host name, as was asked in the original question.  Ironically, it looks like the underlying native tool Android uses behind the scenes *can* resolve hosts, but it doesn't seem to offer a public API to resolve anything but services.

Comment: Actually, it is a sort of answer to me. RPi (with avahi, maybe +samba) advertises its name, other PCs can use it. Android, however, cannot. Unless one makes a some trick in the Android application. Sad, but an answer to me.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27547461/android-resolve-local-mdns